# goでcsv書き込みの際にfloatで書き込みしたい

Tags: go, csv

go言語を用いてcsvの書き込みを試みようとしているのですが，
事情によりstringではなくfloatでの書き込みを求めています．
csvパッケージにwhite関数があるのですが引数がstringのスライスでなければならず，書き込んだcsvの中身もstringになります．

何かよい方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/54313

Comment: `strconv.FormatFloat()` で文字列へ変換(書き込み時)、`strconv.ParseFloat()` で `float32/64` へ変換(読み込み時)してみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: やはり保存はstring,読み込みの際にfloatに変換の方法しかないのでしょうか・・

Comment: CSV 形式ではなく、バイナリ形式で読み書きするとか。https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#example_Write この場合、エンディアンの問題がありますけれども。

Answer (score 1):

CSV と言う以上は Comma Separated Values という「テキストファイル」ですから
`float` を文字列に変換して書き出し
文字列を `float` に変換しながら読み込み
しかないんぢゃないですかね。

「そのまま」の意味が読者にはつかみにくいですが
もしかして `float` の内部表現をそのまま１６進数表記して CSV 形式にするとかですか？
https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8D%98%E7%B2%BE%E5%BA%A6%E6%B5%AE%E5%8B%95%E5%B0%8F%E6%95%B0%E7%82%B9%E6%95%B0
によると、例えば
`+1.0` は `3F80 0000`
`-2.0` は `C000 0000`
なので CSV 形式テキストとして `3F800000,C0000000,` というのはありです。
（そんな CSV を浮動小数点数形式として読んでくれるツールがあるかどうかは知りませんが）